# How can all ActiveRecord attribute accessors be wrapped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a model in which attributes are allowed to be null, but when a null attribute is read I'd like to take a special action.  In particular, I'd like to throw a certain exception.  That is, something like

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def anAttr
      read_attribute(:anAttr) or raise MyException(:anAttr)
  end
end
```

that's all fine, but it means I have to hand-code the identical custom accessor for each attribute.

I thought I could override read_attribute, but my overridden read_attribute is never called.

Comment: I really gotta ask why.  What is your use case here?  Surely there's a better way.  "Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances."  Nil seems hardly exceptional.

Comment: it's a reasonable question, but I haven't got much room to explain here.  in short, we've got a form with many optional fields.  upon submission we want to apply a series of rules against the form. for each rule, we get either "yes", "no" or "not enough info".

that alone doen't suggest the "abort by exception" method.  but we also store the rules externally, in a DSL or sorts which must be as simple as possible.  so the language of the rules themselves can't check for nulls.  instead, the rules just use the values, and the evaluation aborts if there's an access to an undefined value.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you'd need to do this, but alas:

```
def get(attr)
  val = self.send(attr)
  raise MyException unless val
  val
end

@object.get(:name)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's funny, we were looking into this same thing today.  Check into `attribute_method.rb` which is where all the Rails logic for the attributes exists.  You'll see a `define_attribute_methods` method which you should be able to override.

In the end, I think we're going to do this in a different way, but it was a helpful exercise.